# How to export JTable colors to an excel .xls file?

Tags: swing, export-to-excel

How to export JTable java swing /jidesoft cell background colors to excel .xls file?

Comment: why? wouldn't you simply export the data and define the coloring rules in excel itself

Answer (score 0):

if you want to export string value into csv file (excel support it), or you can use other library for example Apache POI.

```
public static void exportJTable (JTable table, String fileName)  throws Exception {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder("");

    for (int i=0; i<table.getModel().getRowCount(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j<table.getModel().getColumnCount(); j++) {
            int col = table.convertColumnIndexToView(j);
            String value = null ;

            try {
                value = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(i, col);
            }
            catch (java.lang.ClassCastException e) {
            }

            if ( value == null)
                value = "" ;

            // CSV file
            value.replaceAll(",", "");
            content.append(value + ",");
        }
        content.append("\n");
    }


    writeToFile(content.toString(),fileName);
}

private static void writeToFile (String data, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file,"UTF-8");

    writer.println(data);

    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: a) -1 for type-casting to String b) -1 for converting the model-columnIndex into view coordinate and then querying the model with it, c) exporting the _color_ is addressed where exactly in your snippet?